# UISegmentedControl tintColor not working in iOS7

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an application I'm trying to get ready to build with the iOS7 SDK.  Unfortunately, we still have a lot of users on iOS5 so we need to support it.

The problem I'm encountering is styling a UISegmentedControl on iOS7 when the NIB is set to open in Xcode 4.6. It simply ignores the tintColor. When I set the NIB file to open in Xcode 5, setting the tintColor works just fine, but I get an error when trying to use the NIB on iOS5. The segmented control is in a Toolbar control.  Below is the code I'm using.

```
toolbar.barTintColor =  [UIColor redColor];
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[toolbar setTranslucent:NO];
[toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**Update:**

What I was seeing with some of my other NIBs was the following behavior for each configuration:

**Opens in 4.6, builds for 5.0 and later** - Works for all versions by can't style segment controller using tintColor

**Opens in 5.0 builds for 5.0 and later** - Works for iOS5 and iOS7 but shows a "Can't locate NIB in bundle" error for iOS6

**Opens in 5.0 builds for 7.0 and later** - Works for iOS7 and iOS6 but crashes on iOS5 with a "Can't locate NIB" error

However, for this specific NIB the "Opens in 5.0 builds for 5.0 and later" configuration seems to be working without crashing. So, that solves my current problem, but I still don't understand why some of my other NIBs won't work with the same configuration...

Comment: Show the error the Xcode gives you when you try to use the nib on iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

The `barTintColor` property was added in iOS 7 so using it in iOS 6 or earlier will cause a crash.

Update your code to guard against misuse:

```
if ([toolbar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: The entire block of code above is surrounded by a check for iOS7, so, that's not the issue.